# UTF-8 Android from Array-Sorted .txt File

Tags: java, android, file-io, utf-8, compatibility

I have seen many questions addressing this issue, but have applied various solutions with no luck, and unfortunately seen that others just do not apply to me.

BACKGROUND - Basically, the user can submit a text-file, and after its placed in the proper directory, the Android application will take it, and, line by line, assembly it into an array, presenting it later after certain action has been taken.

The problem is that all characters from other languages (in this case most primarily Chinese, German, Spanish, and Russian) display as those pesky diamond-question marks. I cannot save language-specific @string/ values because the text file is submitted by the user, all my program really does is present the data after doing a line-by-line txt to array conversion. How can I prime the system for these foreign characters that are from outside of the system itself?

Is this issue simply because I am testing on an older device? Would using a more recent 4.x device fix this entirely?

Thanks and if this is a duplicate please mark as such, sorry.

Thanks again!

Comment: Well what happens when you set the language on the device to the right language for the file? I think if you're reading UTF-8 you have a display problem and not a reading problem.

Comment: The app is part of language-learning though, so multiple languages are needed. I don't know exactly if I use UTF-8 correctly in my question, I really mean special characters like the German double ss

Comment: It seems on my device (HTC One with 4.4.2) even with the language set to English I can display Chinese characters correctly and copy and paste them into all apps. Is this not the case for your device? I think for us to troubleshoot further we would need your code that reads and displays the text, and a sample text file from which you are having the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I will first test this on a newer device, as i was using 2.2 or something old like that, if it doesn't work i will update. By the way i am using a scanner to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> scanFile(someFile) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  File file = new File(Somefile);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
  ArrayList<String> holder = new ArrayList<>();
  while(in.hasNestLine())
  {

     holder.add(nextLine());

 }
 if (condition is true){
     return holder; // returns the ArrayList of line Strings
 }
 else
 {
  return holder.clear();// or return an empty ArrayList for safty
 }
 file.close();
 in.close();
```

}

Comment: you need to install a language pack on the system for the foreign characters.